# Shell Script variable inside a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm writing a shell script as below.

```
#/bin/bash

ip1="1.1.1.1"
ip2="2.2.2.2"

for ((i=1; i<=2; i++))
do
echo "$[ip$i]"

done
```

i get the error after run.
./1.sh: line 8: 1.1.1.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1.1.1")

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Use indirect variable expansion.

```
#/bin/bash

ip1="1.1.1.1"
ip2="2.2.2.2"

for ((i=1; i<=2; i++))
do
  var="ip$i"
  echo "${!var}"
done
```

However, a better idea is to use an array.

```
ips=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" )
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
   echo "$ip"
done

for ((i=1; i<=${#ip[@]}; i++)); do
   echo "${ips[i]}"
done
```